# SciPy curve_fit returns weird fitted curve

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy, curve-fitting, logistic-regression

I just tried to fit a curve to a bunch of points that looks like a logistic function, and the result is like a tangled curve.

This is the code:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def logistic(v, m, n, a, t):
    return a * (1 + m * np.exp(-v/t))/(1 + n * np.exp(-v/t))

def power_curve_fit(xvalues, yvalues):

    xdata = xvalues
    ydata = yvalues

    popt, pcov = curve_fit(logistic, xdata, ydata)

    pc = pd.DataFrame()
    pc['wind_speed'] = xdata
    pc['power_gen'] = ydata 
    pc['Fit'] = logistic(xdata, *popt)

    plt.plot(xdata, logistic(xdata, *popt), 'red')
    plt.scatter(xdata, ydata, c='pink', marker='o')
    return pc
```

The output:
[image]
Any ideas??

Thank you!

Comment: I tried to run the code you posted, and with no import statements or data it does not work, Also, calling plt.show() will help in displaying the plot. My suggestion is to post a complete working Python script along with a link to the data.

Comment: Your x-data are not sorted, that's why your plot looks strange. Create a different x_fit range with np.linspace(0, 15, 1000),  calculate the y_fit values and plot them. See?